# Countifs multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to count the number of times that all 3 criteria are matched, as shown below:

```
     A    B    C    D
1  12%  Yes  2.0  1.9
2   6%  Yes  0.6  2.2
3  -2%  Yes  4.8  4.0
4  11%   No  6.0  4.2
5   5%   No  3.5  3.9
```

3 criteria include:
Column A is greater than 10%,
Column B is "Yes", and
Column C > Column D

Here's my formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, ">=0.1", B:B, "Yes", C:C, ">="&D:D)
```

As you can see, only Row 1 fits all the criteria, and it supposedly would return 1. However, it returns 0 no matter how I amend my formula.

EDIT: I'm pretty sure the `C:C, ">="&D:D` is causing the error, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `">=" & D:D` is basically a standalone text function ("`&`" is a shortcut for the [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.office.com/article/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2) function) and therefore doesn't know which row you're referring to (so you're saying *"greater than or equal to **all** of column `D`"*).

One solution would be to add "helper column".  For example if `E1` had a formula:

```
=C1>=D1
```

...which was then copied down to the rest of the column, then you could get your desired result with formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, ">=0.1", B:B, "Yes", E:E, TRUE)
```

<del>(There's another solution using an array formula but it eludes me at the moment.)</del>

---

**Edit:** heh, the array formula solution eluded me because **you already had the correct formula** to use as an array formula --

....so, use your existing formula, but *instead of hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>* to enter it, use **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>**.

---

### More Information:

- Office Support: Videos: [Array Formulas](https://support.office.com/article/video-array-formulas-8ff8257a-b28e-4e81-b4f8-30f793412dfa)
- Office Support: [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

Comment: Thanks ashleedawg, I followed your advice and used the array formula with Ctrl + Shift + Enter, but it returned 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sumproduct`

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A>=0.1), --( B:B = "Yes"), --(C:C >= D:D))`

or 
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A5>=0.1), --( B1:B5 = "Yes"), --(C1:C5 >= D1:D5))`

Comment: Thanks Baris. Not sure why it returns an incorrect result on a larger scale of data when I use the entire columns. However, the specific row such as A1:A100000 works well.

Answer (score 1):

An olde style array formula produces the correct results.

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A5>0.1, IF(B1:B5="yes", IF(C1:C5>D1:D5, 1))))
```

Finish this with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, not just Enter.